# Jquery.Ajax can not going to url

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to using Ajax  with PHP and I want to delete from MySQL database using ajax without refresh web page 
 but the problem is when I want to delete one row from a table it not go to delete page where the delete operation done 
the code of my ajax is

```
$('.modal2c').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this);
    var del_id = element.attr("id");
    var info 'id='del_id;
    var action = 'delete';
    alert(info);
    ssi_modal.confirm({
        content: 'Are you sure you want to exit?',
        okBtn: {
            className: 'btn btn-primary'
        },
        cancelBtn: {
            className: 'btn btn-danger'
        }
    }, function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "photo.php",
                dataType: 'text',
                data: info,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(info);
                    $('#' + info).fadeOut();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
            ssi_modal.notify('success', {
                content: 'Result: ' + result
            });
        }
        else  ssi_modal.notify('error', {
            content: 'Result: ' + result
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the code the confirm dialog is shown and I press ok but nothing happening I don't know where is the wrong 
I have been searched about 2 hours but I don't found solution

Comment: any errors in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: If you cannot read it ___you cannot debug it___ Formatting the code makes it easier for us to read and understand and ___easier for you to debug it___

Comment: `elsessi_modal.notify(....` Surely that wont compile!!!!

Comment: thank you at now code more easy to be reading

Comment: @muhammad-khaled are you sure "photo.php" is not executed? If so, please show us your console errors.

Comment: thank you very much I am so sorry about that I have wrong in my code so photo.php not executed I solved it